# LibGDX IntelliJ Gradle Project Creation Error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I am new to IntelliJ and Gradle and I am trying to get a project started up using LibGDX with IntelliJ and Gradle. I have followed the instructions on LibGDX website but when I get to the spot where I open up the LibGDX project I get a message in IntelliJ telling me that

```
Error:org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.11-all\7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj\gradle-1.11'.: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.11-all\7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj\gradle-1.11'.
```

I am using Windows 7, IntelliJ 13 Community Edition and LibGDX 1.1. I have looked up the error on Google and on this very site but can find nothing which helped. I have restarted my computer several times and reinstalled all software including Java several times and nothing has changed anything with this error. Anyone know what is going on here? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I answered the question myself. If you are using a 64 bit OS and you are getting this error then you have to reinstall IntelliJ and when you are **starting it up again for the first time** you have to use the 64 bit exe file. This can be found in the installation folder for IntelliJ in the bin folder and is called idea64.exe. As I only have IntelliJ 13 Community Edition I could only test it on this version, so if you are using a different version then you might have to solve this another way.